# How to solve problem of DUMP not working in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
I have Apache Pig version 0.17.0 (r1797386) .
I executed the following code. I have hadoop 2.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

While run pig in mapreduce mode it gives following messages:
21/11/12 09:47:37 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
21/11/12 09:47:37 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
21/11/12 09:47:37 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
21/11/12 09:47:37 WARN pig.Main: Cannot write to log file: /home/hadoop/hadoop-      2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/pig_1636690657754.log
2021-11-12 09:47:37,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.17.0
```

(r1797386) compiled Jun 02 2017, 15:41:58

```
2021-11-12 09:47:37,785 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2021-11-12 09:47:37,997 [main] INFO
```

org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2021-11-12 09:47:37,997 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000
2021-11-12 09:47:38,390 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Pig Script ID for the session: PIG-default-51d35c23-16a2-42eb-9868-d9aa4a7aea0f
2021-11-12 09:47:38,390 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - ATS is disabled since

```
yarn.timeline-service.enabled set to false
grunt> 

I run a simple pig code:

grunt>A = LOAD '/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
grunt>DUMP A;

**While I run DUMP A; it gives following error messages:**
2021-11-12 09:52:07,615 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2021-11-12 09:52:07,628 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2021-11-12 09:52:07,629 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2021-11-12 09:52:07,629 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NestedLimitOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2021-11-12 09:52:07,630 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2021-11-12 09:52:07,632 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2021-11-12 09:52:07,632 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2021-11-12 09:52:07,643 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
2021-11-12 09:52:07,645 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8050
2021-11-12 09:52:07,648 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2021-11-12 09:52:07,648 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2021-11-12 09:52:07,649 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2021-11-12 09:52:08,226 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pig-0.17.0/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-849926297/tmp-1952067843/pig-0.17.0-core-h2.jar
2021-11-12 09:52:08,381 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pig-0.17.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-849926297/tmp764505864/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2021-11-12 09:52:08,951 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pig-0.17.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-849926297/tmp1481980209/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2021-11-12 09:52:09,089 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pig-0.17.0/lib/joda-time-2.9.3.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-849926297/tmp789184813/joda-time-2.9.3.jar
2021-11-12 09:52:09,092 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2021-11-12 09:52:09,094 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2021-11-12 09:52:09,094 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2021-11-12 09:52:09,094 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2021-11-12 09:52:09,145 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2021-11-12 09:52:09,160 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8050
2021-11-12 09:52:09,266 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2021-11-12 09:52:09,310 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage - Using PigTextInputFormat
2021-11-12 09:52:09,317 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1636690618976_0002
2021-11-12 09:52:09,331 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob - PigLatin:DefaultJobName got an error while submitting 
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:301)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:271)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:393)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:280)
    ... 18 more
2021-11-12 09:52:09,652 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1636690618976_0002
2021-11-12 09:52:09,652 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases A
2021-11-12 09:52:09,652 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: A[1,4],A[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2021-11-12 09:52:09,661 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2021-11-12 09:52:14,674 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2021-11-12 09:52:14,674 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1636690618976_0002 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2021-11-12 09:52:14,675 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2021-11-12 09:52:14,682 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8050
2021-11-12 09:52:14,694 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1636690618976_0002. Redirecting to job history server.
2021-11-12 09:52:15,695 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:16,696 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:17,698 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:18,699 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:19,702 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:20,703 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:21,704 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:22,705 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:23,707 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:24,708 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:24,823 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1636690618976_0002. Redirecting to job history server.
2021-11-12 09:52:25,825 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:26,827 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:27,828 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:28,830 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:29,831 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:30,833 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:31,834 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:32,836 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:33,837 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:34,839 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:34,956 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Could not get Job info from RM for job job_1636690618976_0002. Redirecting to job history server.
2021-11-12 09:52:35,958 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:36,960 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:37,961 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:38,963 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:39,965 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:40,966 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:41,968 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:42,970 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:43,972 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:44,973 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2021-11-12 09:52:45,080 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2021-11-12 09:52:45,080 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2021-11-12 09:52:45,081 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.9.2   0.17.0  hadoop  2021-11-12 09:52:07 2021-11-12 09:52:45 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1636690618976_0002  A   MAP_ONLY    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:301)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:271)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:393)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:280)
    ... 18 more
    hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/tmp/temp-849926297/tmp-249405812,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/tmp/temp-849926297/tmp-249405812"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1636690618976_0002


2021-11-12 09:52:45,082 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2021-11-12 09:52:45,087 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A. Backend error : java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2021-11-12 09:52:45,087 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - There is no log file to write to.
2021-11-12 09:52:45,087 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias A. Backend error : java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1010)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:782)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:383)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:841)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:473)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:290)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1475)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1460)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1119)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1082)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:995)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:214)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.getTaskReports(MRJobStats.java:528)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:823)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From sudip-lenovo/10.14.14.198 to localhost:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getJobReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getJobReport(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:325)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3600(Client.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    ... 35 more

grunt>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps that you should lookinto myfiles1.txt files as it seems to be missing/have incorrect permissions.

```
hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.2/Pig/pigprogs/myfile1.txt
```